Detect if current settings language in iOS is Latin OR non-Latin (e.g. chinese, japanese)
Currently I used this snippet to check language code (ISO. e.g. en, fr), but now I want to check if there is any way in iOS SDK to detect if preferred language in iOS is Latin OR non-Latin locales (e.g. japanese, chinese, etc.)
private func currentLanguageCode() -> String? {
        guard #available(iOS 16, *), let localeLanguageCode = Locale.current.language.languageCode else {
            return Locale.current.languageCode
        }
        return localeLanguageCode.identifier
    }

Just something like func isLatinLanguage() -> Bool checking default user settings language.

I think you will have to do this yourself, eg have an array of all the language codes that you consider latin (
Romance languages) and test if your currentLanguageCode is contained in this array.
See also ISO-639  eg Set-5, language groups

Please precisely define what counts as a "Latin" language. Presumably a language that is written in the Latin alphabet is a Latin language, but what if that language can also be written in a non-Latin script? e.g. is Ainu a Latin language? This feels like an XY problem - why are you trying to determine this in the first place? What difference is this going to make?

Also note that Latin itself is a language. I would recommend editing the question to make it clear that you don't mean the actual Latin language itself.

The OP is asking about iOS Locale.Language code
for non-latin, which as mentioned, they should defined, but do not.
Note, Latin, Ainu are not part of the system Locale.Language in iOS,
no need to worry about them.

@workingdogsupportUkraine Yeah, Ainu is a bad example. A better example is Inuktitut. .language.script says it's not Latin, but it is definitely written in Latin in some parts of the world. Perhaps a region code can make a difference, but I'm not sure.

Inuktitut, learned something new today. There is a languageCode for it iu, but I cannot see it in the list of Locale.Language.systemLanguages.

@workingdogsupportUkraine The script (writing system) is a factor of the entire locale. It is not precisely tied to the language (though obviously it is extremely related). Scripts for can be specified with extended codes. For example, Chinese written in simplified script is zh-Hans, which traditional script is zh-Hant. I haven't looked at Inuktitut, but I would expect iu-Cans vs iu-Latn. Often adding a country identifier (such as iu_CA, though I haven't checked what that does) will adjust the default writing system. You can also have regional script variations like zh-Hans_HK.

It can get pretty complex and Foundation takes all the parts pretty seriously. A good brief intro are in Apple's docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LanguageandLocaleIDs/LanguageandLocaleIDs.html

The thing you're looking for is the script:
Locale(identifier: "fr").language.script   // Latn
Locale(identifier: "en").language.script   // Latn
Locale(identifier: "vi").language.script   // Latn
Locale(identifier: "zh").language.script   // Hans
Locale(identifier: "ja").language.script   // Jpan

So to your question:
func isLatinLanguage() -> Bool {
    Locale.current.language.script == .latin
}


Actually, if I had to give more details in the description of the question Locale.current.numberingSystem is the thing I was looking for. Thanks
